# Java Script split.length return only 1 but why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, split

I have a question concerning the split function in java script. In my example the split.length method return only "1", but why? The variable "singleWords" includes only "" (or in other words: nothing)

Here is the code:

```
var singleWords = jQuery(elementId).text().split(",");
if (singleWords.length == 0) {
  // if case
} else {
  // else case      
}
```

The Value of jQuery(elementId).text() is: "ABC, XYZ, OOP" and the value of singleWords is ""

Comment: Can you do a JSFiddle showing this please?

Comment: What are the values of `elementId` and `jQuery(elementId).text()`?

Comment: `singleWords` can't contain nothing at all, it would have to be an array though it may be an array with only one element that is an empty string.

Answer (score 4):

This is because split function return array that contain only single element if no delimiter find.

Answer (score 4):

`split` returns an array of strings made from the original one. Since you don't have the separator in your original string, split returns an array containing just the original string. Thus, the length of the array is 1 as it contains just one element.

Answer (score 3):

If your `elementId` variable contains an element's id (as its name suggests) then `jQuery(elementId)` will return a jQuery object with *no* elements, and `jQuery(elementId).text()` will be an empty string `""`. And an empty string that has been `.split()` will return an array with one element (the empty string), so then `singleWords.length` will be 1.

To select an element by id you need `jQuery("#" + elementId)`:

```
var singleWords = jQuery("#" + elementId).text().split(",");
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/s3c3H/

Or if your element is an `<input>` element you need to use `.val()` rather than `.text()`:

```
var singleWords = jQuery("#" + elementId).val().split(",");
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/s3c3H/1/

Also the code would need to run after the element has been parsed, so it would need to be included in a script block after the element in question and/or wrapped in a document ready handler.

Answer (score 2):

Function `split` always returns at least one element, and when it does so, that element is identical to the input string for which you requested the split.